# Finding an <a> contains the text Starred with XPath

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

In the chrome console, I enter the following xpath commands to find an  elements that contains the text "Starred", but chrome does not seem to able to find it. The XPath I use is:

```
//a[contains(text(), "Starred")]
```

Is there anything wrong with this xpath?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: @TGH you can try gmail, where there is a Starred item when you login

Comment: Question on SO should be self-contained and include all relevant information to answer the problem. Please provide some example HTML which you want to match in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me in both Elements and Console. Chrome Version 51.0.

Did you remember to wrap the xPath in `$x(" ")` when searching through the console?

[image]

[image]